# Can't detect Chromecast if it is built-in a TV

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

I am working on a project which needs to have casting capability. I have implemented the Cast SDK several times and am relatively experienced with it, however I do have this strange issue. The cast SDK can't detect a Chromecast device, when the Chromecast is built in a TV. If the device is a standard dongle everything works as expected.

Just to clarify I am having problems only with the discovery. If the device is discovered everything works.

My coworkers (for Android and Web ) are reporting the same behaviour.

Has anyone experienced such a problem?

Comment: What type of TVs? Some TVs - like Samsung - show up in Youtube (for example) as a "Cast" device (same icon), but are using another approach to stream data, e.g. DLNA/UPNP streaming, or open a specific Youtube app that might be preinstalled on the device.